TSC errors when running gulp serve
I am trying to use typescript in a sharepoint project and the botframework using the botframework-webchat library. when I do that it gives me all these errors:
17:03:42] Error - [tsc] node_modules/botframework-webchat-core/node_modules/valibot/dist/index.d.ts(2170,109): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[17:03:42] Error - [tsc] node_modules/botframework-webchat-core/node_modules/valibot/dist/index.d.ts(2197,79): error TS1005: ')' expected.
[17:03:42] Error - [tsc] node_modules/botframework-webchat-core/node_modules/valibot/dist/index.d.ts(2197,99): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[17:03:42] Error - [tsc] node_modules/botframework-webchat-core/node_modules/valibot/dist/index.d.ts(2197,113): error TS1005: ';' expected.

I tried doing this in the tsconfig.json: skipLibCheck: true and
"exclude": [
     "**/node_modules/**/valibot"
   ]

But no luck. Here is my code attached. Any idea how to start debugging these issues when working with sharepoint projects?
this is the statement I have in my app customizer code:
 import { createDirectLine, renderWebChat } from 'botframework-webchat';


This is my dependencies section in package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-application-base": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.19.0",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.18.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "valibot": "^1.0.0-beta.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.20.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }

What can I do?

This looks like some Typescript compatibility issues. You can try below several ways:

Update TypeScript: Since valibot version 1.0.0-beta.8 might require a newer TypeScript version, try updating TypeScript to the
latest version:
npm install typescript@latest


Use skipLibCheck: Add the skipLibCheck option to your tsconfig.json to skip type checking of declaration files:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}


Downgrade valibot: If the issue persists, you might need to downgrade valibot to a more stable version that is known to work well
with your setup:
npm install valibot@0.31.0



I am using SPFx 1.20.0 with "botframework-webchat": "^4.15.9", dependency and its working as expected.
